# Why doesn't height:auto work on these two elements?

Tags: css, layout, html

I want my main-div and footer-div grow with the content (height:auto). height:auto works fine for the footer, but not for the main content. When I try it for the main-wrapper it messes up the page. To be exact, the footer takes over the whole footer and main together. The structure of my page is something like this:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="main-wrapper"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the css of each div:

```
#page-wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto; 
    width:85%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 6px 0 4px  -4px #888 , -6px 0 4px  -4px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 0 4px  -4px #888 , -6px 0 4px  -4px #888;
    box-shadow: 6px 0 4px  -4px #888 , -6px 0 4px  -4px #888;
    border-right:solid 1px #CCC;
    border-left:solid 1px #CCC;
}
#header{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ffffff;

}
#main-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:auto; /* this line is the problem */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#E5E7EE;
}
#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Inside main-wrapper I have these 2 divs:

```
#text-wrapper{
    width:60%;
    float:left;
    font-weight:300;
    padding-left:50px; 
 }

#login-register-field{
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    height:260px;
    background-color:#BDBCC4;
    -webkit-border-radius:12px;
    -moz-border-radius:12px;
    border-radius:12px;
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top:80px;
    position:relative;

}
```

Could these be causing the problem?

Comment: `height: auto` is the default for `<div>` elements. What happens if you just don't set it at all? Your `<div>` should expand to fit it's contents.

Comment: Have you tried this layout without specifying height:auto? The general rule is that divs will have the sizeof their contents.

Comment: JamWaffles and @AlexanderPavlov, I removed height:auto in both of them and I still get the same result.

Comment: Try doing so to its parent divs.

Comment: @Keeper, the parent div is page-wrapper and I didn't specify any height for that. Should I also remove the height in header? I wouldn't think that would be the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no content inside both divs and css height property default is auto so you don't need to explicitly state it is unless it was overwritten by some other style rule.

If you left the divs empty on purpose of posting this issue then I believe whatever is causing the problem is missing.

There is no issue with growing with the content as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cufR9/)

Comment: Yes, I left them empty just for this question. I updated my question with two divs inside page-wrapper div. Maybe those are causing the problem.

Comment: When using floats you need to add the container overflow: auto in order to let the container flow to the bottom of the content properly.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cufR9/4/

Answer (score 1):

Define the height of the body and div, and you get what you asked for.
http://jsfiddle.net/r4mK7/2/

Comment: This almost solves my problem. main-wapper and footer are not anymore children of the page-wrapper, which is weird.

Comment: I can still see them as children of page-wrapper. If you're using FireFox, try the Firebug tool.

Comment: You can give them height yourself, or, like "Maayan Glikser" answered there, you should probably put some content in your divs in order to see them.

Comment: Yes they are, but the page-wrapper doesn't have the same height as header,main and footer together, which is what I want. The shadow is not around the whole main now.

Comment: Which is the case in your fiddle btw :)

Comment: Thank you! setting height:auto also for page-wrapper solved the problem :D

Comment: sorry man! My bad. It doesn't actually work always. Now all the divs have the same height :(

Comment: I was about to propose you limit your header, main and footer heights to 20%, 60% and 20% respectively, it may help as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7892/discussion-between-keeper-and-nima)

Answer (score 0):

May using MAX and MIN heigh attributes be another solution, somthink like:

```
#page-wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto; 
    width:85%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 6px 0 4px  -4px #888 , -6px 0 4px  -4px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 0 4px  -4px #888 , -6px 0 4px  -4px #888;
    box-shadow: 6px 0 4px  -4px #888 , -6px 0 4px  -4px #888;
    border-right:solid 1px #CCC;
    border-left:solid 1px #CCC;
}
#header{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ffffff;

}
#main-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:auto; /* this line is the problem */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#E5E7EE;
}
#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 30px;/* or 0 if you wan to hide on null content*/
    background-color:#ADFADF;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```